# Find correct time on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, time, nsdate, utc

I want to find out correct time on iOS devices even though user have set wrong time manually. 
In the setting->General->Date & Time there is option of Set Automatically if that option is uncheck by the user then how can i find the correct time programmatically.

Comment: Network Time Protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol Here's an NTP client implementation for iOS: https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp

Answer (score 3):

Use NTP protocol for getting a current time or serve a time from your server and get it on application launch.

Apple doesn't provide by default any way to get time from NTP unfortunately and all time related function are using local time that user can change.

Comment: You can use `https://github.com/huynguyencong/NHNetworkTime`. That is an open source to get correct time from some default NTP server, or you can set your time server

Answer (score 0):

I have a 'web service' on my site which serves you the [current time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch](http://currentmillis.com/api/millis-since-unix-epoch.php), one request, one response, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the wrong place for this question. Try Apple's forums.

Because there is no way to get current time form ios device when user update time manually.

Sweet & smart .........